# USB 3.0 enumeration process did not start after successful link training and initialization

Tags: usb

I'm developing a USB 3.0 interface for my FPGA/Zynq based embedded system using a PHY chip. The problem I encountered is that after successful link training and link initialization, the device did not receive any enumeration related packets, including the address assigning ones.

To be more precise, when link training and link initialization were finished, the device did receive two LMPs (link management packets), one is PortCapabilities and the other is PortConfiguration. I responded with PortCapabilities and PortConfigurationResponse LMP just as it says in the spec.

Theoretically, by now the host (windows7 PC) should start the enumeration process with assigning an address to the device, but the only packets I got from the host are ITPs (isochronous timing packets), nothing else.

I wonder if I missed something in the spec. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Sorry, I want to know why didn't I  receive any enumeration related packets (like assigning address) from the host and how can I fix that